# Is turning on a Centos system pretty easy?

Tags: centos

Yes, the question I'm asking is simplistic to the extreme.  I'm sorry about that.  I'm not a Linux expert, certainly not from a system admin point of view, so I've got to ask a very simple question.  We have a Centos system here, which we're not really responsible for.  At the moment I've got 5 other servers taking power on a precarious UPS.  I want to shut down the Centos system to help alleviate things, while we work to get the new UPS.  I've gone to the Centos monitor, and it looks to me as though it's simply a process of clicking on the "Shut down" link on the lower right.  Is there anything else, or will that do?

Comment: well it depends on the system, and the sysadmin, but ya know - a nice romantic dinner, some soft music, slightly revealing attire, maybe show a little leg... do it right and you'll have the system up in no time!  (I'm sorry. I couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - the "shutdown" button will do what you expect it to. You may be prompted for administrator credentials before the shutdown will proceed.

Needless to say, you'll lose access to any data or applications that are on that server.

With regards to starting things back up, whether or not applications start back up automatically is completely dependent on how the server is configured, so YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to shut down and power up Linux systems, in the general case.  It is remotely possible that something odd has been done that will cause you trouble, but unlikely, and absolutely not the default.

Other than clicking the "shut down" link, you can use the command line `poweroff` command as root, or you can hit "Ctrl-Alt-Del" at the text login prompt to trigger a clean reboot.  (Again, by default, that can be turned off.)

Booting should just be a matter of turning on the system - it should come up without any human intervention at all.